# Syntax error in my JSDoc type when key is named "event"

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

Here is a jsdoc that the jsdoc plugin of eslint does not like:

```
@property {{event: Object.<string, MyEnum[]>, observation: Object.<string, MyEnum[]>}} enums
```

It complains: `Syntax error in type: (...)  jsdoc/valid-types`

If I rename "event" to "events", it works again.

Any idea why I am not allowed to have an object key named "event"?

**SOLVED (by andrew arrow, see his solution below):**

Thanks to @andrew arrow, I ended up decomposing my "enums" key like this, and it did not complain anymore:

```
@property {Object} enums
@property {Object.<string, MyEnum[]>} enums.event
@property {Object.<string, MyEnum[]>} enums.observation
```

Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is specific to the JSDoc annotation and the ESLint JSDoc plugin. The plugin might be mistakenly interpreting "event" as something else, triggering the "Syntax error in type" complaint!

Try an alternative syntax for the JSDoc annotation to see if it works without any errors. Instead of using the inline type notation for the property use the @type tag with a separate @typedef for MyEnum:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, MyEnum[]>} MyEnumObject
 * @property {MyEnumObject} event
 * @property {MyEnumObject} observation
 *
 * @type {{
 *   event: MyEnumObject,
 *   observation: MyEnumObject
 * }}
 */
const enums = {
  // Your object initialization here
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Andrew. This is not a variable, it's an Object property, I'm pretty sure I'm allowed to name a property the way I want? I've been using this object without issue for years, it's just now that I am being a little more strict on my JSDoc annotations that I have this JSDoc-only issue.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I ended up decomposing the "enums" key with "enums.event" and "enums.observation", and while cumbersome, it worked :) thanks! (did not try your specific example though)